# Change Windows Scaling in Python

Tags: python, windows, windows-10

I'm trying to streamline a process of setting up a computer. I'm using python to streamline this process, one of the processes that needs to be done is setting the scaling of windows. I have no idea how to approach this. I tried implementing some techniques similar to adjusting the screen resolution, but I can't seem to find how to relate those to the scaling

I've tried looking into Pywin32

Comment: Did you try the techniques outlined by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35233182/how-can-i-change-windows-10-display-scaling-programmatically-using-c-sharp)? Even though the question is about C#, they ought to be doable in Python - since it only involves changing the registry and the resolution (the latter which you said you already can do).

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable at all in C# so it is hard for me to translate some of that. The change resolution portion of my program looks much simpler than the link posted

Comment: What do you mean by "windows scaling"?

Comment: https://imgur.com/HpNbEIi

Comment: @BrandonChiu I was thinking of a more high-level translation than a literal one, as in change the registry key and then the resolution, not necessarily how they do it, but accomplish the same things just via Python instead