# Automate changing Windows 10 scaling?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd, windows-10

I am trying to automate the process of changing the user's Windows scaling to 100% (right click desktop --> Display settings). As of right now I have a batch script using SendKeys to do everything then close out of settings.

I have tried writing a PS script to change LogPixels but having to sign out every time for changes to take affect is something I'd like to avoid.

Any other way you can think of accomplishing this besides the batch script? Is there a way to alter LogPixels and have it take affect with signing the user out?

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't do this via the registry method and not need to log in and out.

If you want to look at C# for this, there's a very through answer here:
[How can I change Windows 10 Display Scaling Programmatically using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35233182/how-can-i-change-windows-10-display-scaling-programmatically-using-c-sharp)