# ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1) decreases windows resolution

Tags: python, tkinter, ctypes

```
import tkinter as tk
import ctypes
 
ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)
 
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x150")
 
label = tk.Label(root, text = "Hello World")
label.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
 
root.mainloop()
```

As you can see the difference between both the windows but the quality is enhanced, now how can I get the resolution as before without changing it using geometry attribute?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Windows and others, exist an option to change the Scaling size, 100% by default, to improve the usability in smaller screens with high resolution, mostly laptops:

[Display settings in Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iON0Z.png)

This setting changes the size of each element including all windows frames, not only Tk. The best wave is to increase the window resolution. But if you are looking to rescale in base this windows settings, will be harder.

I recommend checking about win32con, pywintypes, win32api. Also this another question:
[How can I change Windows 10 Display Scaling Programmatically using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35233182/how-can-i-change-windows-10-display-scaling-programmatically-using-c-sharp)

windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1) will change the windows resolution, including the menu size text, at least your screen settings are on 100%. Is good to recommend using this to change only inside elements, but it will not change the window size:

```
root.tk.call('tk', 'scaling', 1.0)
```