# Delphi change scale and layout

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to make my program change the layout scale at runtime. I developed this code based on an existing powershell script. But it compiles but when running, it returns an error.

Error:

> The procedure entry point SystemParametersInfo could not be located in the dynamic link library.

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;

  function SystemParametersInfo(uiAction, uiParam: UINT; pvParam: Pointer; fWinIni: UINT): BOOL; stdcall; external 'user32.dll';

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function SetScaling: Boolean;
begin
 Result := SystemParametersInfo($000F, 125, nil, 1);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 SetScaling;
end;
```

Comment: Why not calling `Windows.SystemParametersInfo()` right away, which every Delphi version already imports?

Comment: Why did you remove the code?

Answer (score 1):

As it is said in the mentioned error there is no function named `SystemParametersInfo` in `user32.dll`.

There are two similarly named functions [SystemParametersInfoA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa) which is to be used by applications that work with ANSI strings and [SystemParametersInfoW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfow) which is to be used by applications supporting wide strings like modern Delphi.

NOTE: [SystemParametersInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/ms940383(v=msdn.10)) can only be found on Windows CE 5.0 and it resides in `Coredll.lib` library.

Comment: which direction should i take?

Comment: If using Delphi 2007 or newer then `SystemParametersInfoW ` would most likely be the correct be the correct choice unless you are purposely limiting your application into making use of ANSI Strings..

Comment: @SilverWarior Delphi Unicode versions started with Delphi 2009!

Answer (score 1):

The WinAPI.Windows unit defines the SystemParametersInfo function.  No reason to define it locally.

Your call to SystemParametersInfo with a first parameter of $000F is a request to set the screen saver timeout to 125 seconds ($000F=SPI_SETSCREENSAVETIMEOUT).

Setting DPI Scaling is a bit more complex than what you are attempting in the code that you posted. You can read the "how-to" details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35233182/how-can-i-change-windows-10-display-scaling-programmatically-using-c-sharp).